# MySql Query With Two table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables let say `table1` & `table2`

`table1` contains `uniqueId, name1, name2, value fields`

`table2` contains `id, uniqueName, keywords fields`

`table2.keyworks` *have comma separate names*.

**So, what I am trying to do is below.**

```
select * from table1 
//1> replace table1.name1 with table2.uniqueName  if table2.keywords has 
//table1.name1 
//2> replace table1.name2 with table2.uniqueName if table2.keywords has 
//table1.name2
```

Comment: use FIND_IN_SET() function in mysql.

Comment: thanks @PrasannaKumarJ but I also want to replace table1.name2 and table1.name1

Comment: @AabirHussain . . . You should probably ask *another * question, specifically about updating the table.  You should explain why your data model is using comma-delimited values (this is a bad idea and you can forestall discussion of the matter).

Comment: @GordonLinoff I can understand what you are trying to say but I can't update that table because it is used by more then 3 application and My Client need it (what I am trying to achieve) for the 4th application. All these application have heavy traffic so some we have to do dirty work some time .

Answer (score 0):

```
select *,(case when FIND_IN_SET(table.name1,table2.keywords)>0 then table1.name1 
                when FIND_IN_SET(table.name1,table2.keywords)>0 then table1.name2 end)from table1
```

Try this.

Comment: I can't update those fields. I just need to replace in select query so that fields contain its original values and I get unique Name only in one query.

Comment: yup! some thing like that but it is not  covering my complete solution.